# Get time stamp on Twilio app unit url

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

I noticed that Twilio does not send a time stamp on the unit url of a phone voice app. Where can I get this from that is not the rest api or the status call back url. Why no time stamp on all webhooks?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the unit url? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Hi Phil, I want to receive a time stamp on my side of when the call originated. What I mean by the init url is the main Twilio voice app url not the status callback. Makes sense?